# Run code only when all bindings are ready

Tags: javascript, aurelia

So I'm writing this Aurelia application and one thing annoys me a lot. Say I have a custom component defined like this:

```js
export class CustomComponent {
    @bindable callbackForSomething;
    @bindable anotherCallback;
}
```

Now, I have a couple of cases where I have to bind even more functions (or just anything else) on my component. So in each component I have code like this:

```js
callbackForSomethingChanged() {
    this._tryRunComponent();
}

anotherCallbackChanged() {
    this._tryRunComponent();
}

_tryRunComponent() {
    if (!this.callbackForSomething || !this.anotherCallback) {
        return;
    }

    // run some logic here when I know the component is ready
}
```

Does AureliaJS have something to make this easier? With only two properties it's annoying, but I have components declaring a lot more properties.

Comment: I don't use Aurelia, but from a general JS standpoint it looks like a great time to use Promises. Take a look at using `Promise.all()` to only continue after each binding has resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `bind` method to your view-model. It will be invoked by Aurelia once all of the bindable properties have been assigned.

Subsequent changes to the bindable properties will trigger your `*Changed` methods.

Comment: Awwww, damn! I knew this FW has to have something like this. Thanks!